# nl80211: Could not configure driver mode

Tags: drivers, hostapd

**Configuration file: hostapd.conf**

nl80211: Could not configure driver mode

nl80211: deinit ifname=wlan0mon disabled_11b_rates=0

nl80211 driver initialization failed.

wlan0mon: interface state UNINITIALIZED->DISABLED

wlan0mon: AP-DISABLED

wlan0mon: CTRL-EVENT-TERMINATING

hostapd_free_hapd_data: Interface wlan0mon wasn't started

I wanted to try creating a Access Point but I am unable to do it due to the error mentioned above.
Please help me with this problem.
Thanks in advance. :)